# NullReferenceException Error When Trying to Change the Property IsEnabled of an AppBar Item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, tiles

On one of my .xaml pages, I have an appbar with a few icons on it.

One of the icons pins the page to Start, so when it is pinned I want to change the IsEnabled property of that icon to false.

However I get this weird error; as described in the title when this procedure is called.

Here's the code:

```
if (Tile == null) { }
else { appBarPin.IsEnabled = false; }
```

any ideas?

Comment: appBarPin is probably null when you try to set IsEnabled. We'd need to see more code to know for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior with the Application Bar is different to the rest of UI elements. From [App bar for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> The app bar doesn’t support some common features of controls, such as
>   data-binding. As a result, you can’t change the icon button and menu
>   item text by using Name properties that you set in XAML.

If you want to change a property of the appbar item, do it the following way:

```
ApplicationBarIconButton button = (ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
button.IsEnabbled = false;
```

Replace the `0` with the index of the button. I.e. if the button is the second button of the appbar, the index will be 1.

See more in [How to change app bar icon buttons and menu items dynamically for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394044%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

A null reference exception means that you can't say ".IsEnabled" if the thing before the dot is null.

It appears that appBarPin is null.